# Does the order of the sections of code in my _vimrc matter?

Tags: vim

How do the sections of code in the `_vimrc` file interact with each other?
My current file looks like the following but I'm wondering if it matters if a line such as `filetype plugin indent on` is at the start or the end of this file?
Does it matter if a line like `filetype plugin indent on` is repeated twice in the file?
Should the `Pathogen` settings be near the start?

```
"------------------------------------------------------------
    " Must have options {{{1


    "this will make the window maximized on startup
    au GUIEnter * simalt ~x

    " Attempt to determine the type of a file based on its name and possibly its
    " contents. Use this to allow intelligent auto-indenting for each filetype,
    " and for plugins that are filetype specific.
    filetype indent plugin on
    set omnifunc=syntaxcomplete#Complete
    " Enable syntax highlighting
    syntax on

    "set highlight search always on
    :set hlsearch

    "------------------------------------------------------------
    " Usability options {{{1

     " Show partial commands in the last line of the screen
    set showcmd
    " Use case insensitive search, except when using capital letters
    set ignorecase
    set smartcase
    " Allow backspacing over autoindent, line breaks and start of insert action
    set backspace=indent,eol,start
    " When opening a new line and no filetype-specific indenting is enabled, keep
    " the same indent as the line you're currently on. Useful for READMEs, etc.
    set autoindent
    " Stop certain movements from always going to the first character of a line.
    " While this behaviour deviates from that of Vi, it does what most users
    " coming from other editors would expect.
    set nostartofline
    " Display the cursor position on the last line of the screen or in the status
    " line of a window
    set ruler
    " Always display the status line, even if only one window is displayed
    set laststatus=2
    " Instead of failing a command because of unsaved changes, instead raise a
    " dialogue asking if you wish to save changed files.
    set confirm
    " Use visual bell instead of beeping when doing something wrong
    set visualbell
    " And reset the terminal code for the visual bell. If visualbell is set, and
    " this line is also included, vim will neither flash nor beep. If visualbell
    " is unset, this does nothing.
    set t_vb=
    " Enable use of the mouse for all modes
    set mouse=a
    " Set the command window height to 2 lines, to avoid many cases of having to
    " "press <Enter> to continue"
    set cmdheight=2
    " Display line numbers on the left
    set number
    " Quickly time out on keycodes, but never time out on mappings
    set notimeout ttimeout ttimeoutlen=200
    " Use <F11> to toggle between 'paste' and 'nopaste'
    set pastetoggle=<F11>

    "------------------------------------------------------------
    " Indentation options {{{1
    "
    " Indentation settings according to personal preference.

    " Indentation settings for using 2 spaces instead of tabs.
    " Do not change 'tabstop' from its default value of 8 with this setup.
    "set shiftwidth=2
    "set softtabstop=2
    "set expandtab

    " Indentation settings for using hard tabs for indent. Display tabs as
    " two characters wide.
    set shiftwidth=2
    set tabstop=2



    "------------------------------------------------------------
    " Look and Feel {{{1
    "
    " Use CTRL-S for saving, also in Insert mode
    :nnoremap <C-S>     :<C-U>update<CR>
    :vnoremap <C-S>     :<C-U>update<CR>gv
    :cnoremap <C-S>     <C-C>:update<CR>
    :inoremap <C-S>     <C-O>:update<CR>

    "color scheme setting
    " Set nice colors
    " background for normal text is light grey
    " Text below the last line is darker grey
    " Cursor is green, Cyan when ":lmap" mappings are active
    " Constants are not underlined but have a slightly lighter background
    set guifont=Consolas:h16:cANSI
    colorscheme pyte 
    "highlight Normal guibg=grey90
    "highlight Cursor guibg=Green guifg=NONE
    "highlight lCursor guibg=Cyan guifg=NONE
    "highlight NonText guibg=grey80
    "highlight Constant gui=NONE guibg=grey95
    "highlight Special gui=NONE guibg=grey95

    "a quick way to locate python files
    nnoremap <Leader>p :pyf P:\Computer Applications\Python\

    "quick quit command
    noremap <Leader>e :quit<CR> "quits the current window


    "------------------------------------------------------------
    " NERTtree settings {{{1
    "
    "get NERDTree command quick
    nnoremap <Leader>nd :NERDTree M:\
    map <F2> :NERDTreeToggle<CR>
    let NERDTreeQuitOnOpen = 1

    " Rebind <Leader> key...not sure about this one
    "let mapleader = ","

    map <Leader>n <esc>:tabprevious<CR>
    map <Leader>m <esc>:tabnext<CR>

    "------------------------------------------------------------
    " dbext settings {{{1
    "
    "let g:sql_type_default = 'SQLSVR'

     " Since I repeatedly need to edit stored procedures, the CREATE PROCEDURE
    " statement is preceeded by an IF ... END IF block which will drop
    " the procedure or it uses the CREATE OR REPLACE syntax.  
    " This function will visually select the IF block to the END; statement
    " of the stored procedure and execute it.  Or check for the 
    " CREATE OR REPLACE and stop there and look to the end.
    function! SQLExecuteIfCreateReplace()
        let l:old_sel = &sel
        let &sel = 'inclusive'
        let saveWrapScan=&wrapscan
        let saveSearch=@/ 
        let l:reg_z = @z
        let &wrapscan=0
        let @z = ''
        let found = 0
        let startLine = 0
        let endLine = 0
        let curLine = line(".")
        let curCol  = virtcol(".")

        " Must default the command terminator
        let l:dbext_cmd_terminator = ";"

        try
                " Search backwards and do NOT wrap
                " Find the line beginning with an IF clause
                "     IF EXISTS( SELECT 1 ...
                " or find an or replace clause
                "     CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE ...
                " And execute it until we find an 
                "     END 
                " at the beginning of a line.
            let startLine = search('\c\(^\<if\>\|^\<alter\s\+procedure\>\|\<or\s\+replace\>\)', 'bcnW' )

                if startLine > 0
                    " Search forward and visually select all lines
                    " until we find an END; clause
                    let endLine = search('^END'.l:dbext_cmd_terminator.'\s*$', 'cnW')
                    exec startLine.','.endLine.'DBExecRangeSQL'
                endif
            finally
                call cursor(curLine, curCol)
                noh
                let l:query = @z
                let @z = l:reg_z
                let @/=saveSearch
                let &wrapscan=saveWrapScan
                let &sel = l:old_sel
            endtry
        endfunction


    "------------------------------------------------------------
    " pathogen settings {{{1

    "pathogen customization
    "set nocp

    " Use pathogen to easily modify the runtime path to include all plugins under
    " the ~/.vim/bundle directory
    filetype off                    " force reloading *after* pathogen loaded
    call pathogen#infect()
    call pathogen#helptags()
    call pathogen#runtime_append_all_bundles()
    syntax on

    filetype plugin indent on       " enable detection, plugins and indenting in one step
```

Comment: Is there a reason you have added ':set ...' options, instead of 'set ...'? Anyway, if you want `set nocompatible` it is suggested to be first, as settings are applied in order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**tl;dr: Some do, some don't; use a logical structure from simple to complex.**

Pathogen wants its settings to appear at the top, because it modifies the way other scripts are loaded (explicitly via `:runtime`, or as a side effect of calling *autoload functions*).

The order of `:set` usually doesn't matter (unless you have conflicting settings), and any mappings or autocmds you define are only activated after the startup, so you can put them anywhere.

In general, I'd recommend a logical structure, starting with basic stuff like Pathogen, settings, plugin configuration, followed by custom mappings and more involved adaptations like autocmds.

Also, I'd avoid putting filetype-specific stuff into `~/.vimrc`; rather, put those into the corresponding `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/<filetype>.vim` script and use `filetype plugin on`.

Comment: +1 Ingo. You suggest moving the dbext scripts out of `_vimrc` and replace simply with say one line like `SQLdbext plugin on` and then put the script in a file `SQLdbext.vim` and save that file in `~/.vim/after/<filetype>.vim` ....what is "after"?

Comment: The after directories guarantee that the stuff runs _after_ the original filetype plugins that ship with Vim, so you can modify those settings. (Oh, and I had a typo in there.)

Comment: ok - initially I created a file `dbextVimScript.vim` in `~/.vim/dbextFiles/` and then added the line following line to _vimrc: `so M:\dbextFiles\dbextVimScript.vim`. vim seemed to be working ok with that set up. But I have changed to your suggestion as I think it is more standard (added `filetype plugin on` and saved in `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/sql.vim`. Thanks again for your time and advice.

Comment: although in [HERE](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Keep_your_vimrc_file_clean) it says that on a windows machine I should be creating the after directory here in the `vimfiles` directory : `$HOME/vimfiles/after/ftplugin/language.vim`

Answer (score 4):

The order does matter.

e.g. you have two lines:

Options:

```
set nu
set nonu
```

the latter will overwrite the previous setting.

for functions, if you declared a function at the end of your file, but called it at the 1st line. When you load your vimrc the first time, you will get the error `Unknown function: function name`

Also if you manually set some `hi group` before the color scheme (if you used one) loading, the color scheme is gonna overwrite your settings too.

If you call some command/function defined in a plugin before it was loaded, you will have error message too.

so , it is ok if you have some command/setting in vimrc multiple times, but the last one will take effect.